# Cylinder with no cap ends invisible on the inside

Tags: 3d-view, objects

So I'm having this problem with a cylinder. It has no cap ends and the insides don't show up in edit mode. I've already tried flipping and recalculating normals, it did not worked. I've tried creating another cylinder, but it didn't worked too.

Image: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have *Textured Solid* ticked under *Display* in the *Toolshelf*. *You use this feature when you want to display face assigned textures while in solid view.*

[image]